# Am I eligable for another visa after my Working Holiday Visa expires, if i am employed? (Canadian citizen working in the Netherlands)

Tags: visas, netherlands, working-holiday, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen currently working in the Netherlands on a Working Holiday Visa. I am employed, and wanting to stay longer. Am I eligible for another visa?

Comment: Do you mean another working holiday visa, or just any other work visa? If another work visa, it's probably better suited for expats.stackexchange.com, not travel.

Answer (score 2):

This [government website](http://www.rsonac.org/schengen-visa/3.-long-stay--90-days-mvv/mvv-exchange-au-pair--cultural-exchange--working-holiday.html) says the maximum period for a Working Holiday MVV is 1 year.
[This brochure](http://canada.nlembassy.org/binaries/content/assets/postenweb/c/canada/the-embassy-and-consulates-kingdom-of-the-netherlands/import/news/whp/working-holiday-program-netherlands-canada.pdf%5B2%5D) for working holidays says you cannot apply if you have previously used this visa. So it looks like you are not eligible for another working holiday visa.

You could get a 90 day schengen visa, but this does not permit you to work.

You could get an exchange visa as an [au pair](http://www.rsonac.org/schengen-visa/3.-long-stay--90-days-mvv/mvv-exchange-au-pair--cultural-exchange--working-holiday.html#anchor-2-AuPair-REF-Procedure-), but unless this is your current employment that probably doesn't match your plans. There is also something called [Cultural Exchange](http://www.rsonac.org/schengen-visa/3.-long-stay--90-days-mvv/mvv-exchange-au-pair--cultural-exchange--working-holiday.html#anchor-3-CulturalexchangeprogramsinvolvingprivateorganizationsREF-Proc), though I am not sure of details.

Your only other option would be to get an [MVV Employment](http://www.rsonac.org/schengen-visa/3.-long-stay--90-days-mvv/mvv-employment.html), with your employer sponsoring you. I can't speak for Netherlands, but in Australia this is an involved and expensive process for the employer, so they are unlikely to want to do this unless you have some pretty valuable skills.

Comment: Technically you can work on a Schengen visa… but with a separate authorization and only for up to 90 days of course.

Comment: Another small detail: Canadians don't need an MVV, which is a visa, especially if they are already in the country on another visa. They can directly apply for a residence/work permit.

Comment: @Relaxed - I didn't know this, and it comes as quite a surprise!

Answer (score 1):

Like everybody else, you are “eligible” for a regular work visa but it's more complicated and expensive than a working holiday visa. I think it will in any case require help from your employer so it could work if you are doing skilled work and want to stay long-term but not if you simply want to extend a working holiday visa for a few months.

In general, there are three options:

- [Traditional work permit](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/work/working-as-an-employee/Pages/default.aspx)
- [“Highly skilled migrant” scheme](https://ind.nl/en/individuals/residence-wizard/work/highly-skilled-migrant/)
- [EU blue card](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/work/EUbluecard/Pages/default.aspx)

There are some differences in the requirements and consequences (e.g. the EU blue card has stringent minimum salary requirements but is supposed to make it easier to move to another EU country in the future).